# I cannot change the value of an object initialized outside a function or the functions is not running at all - using npm and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm building a social network - and for that I use nodejs. I'm new to the subject, and this's my first post on the subject, I'll be happy if you understand me.

In my social network I want to use an algorithm that has it in the "npm" kmeans algorithm.

I'm trying to run the library I downloaded from npm within my project - but I'm not sure what the problem is. I think the problem is very minor, but for a few hours I sit on it and can't figure it out.

I'm adding the code of what I've done so far:

```
//kmeans.js file

const kmeans = require('kmeans-engine');

exports.addUserkMeansMatch = (req, res) => {
  const engineers = [
    // frontend engineers
    { html: 5, angular: 5, react: 3, css: 3 },
    { html: 4, react: 5, css: 4 },
    { html: 4, react: 5, vue: 4, css: 5 },
    { html: 3, angular: 3, react: 4, vue: 2, css: 3 },

    // backend engineers
    { nodejs: 5, python: 3, mongo: 5, mysql: 4, redis: 3 },
    { java: 5, php: 4, ruby: 5, mongo: 3, mysql: 5 },
    { python: 5, php: 4, ruby: 3, mongo: 5, mysql: 4, oracle: 4 },
    { java: 5, csharp: 3, oracle: 5, mysql: 5, mongo: 4 },

    // mobile engineers
    { objc: 3, swift: 5, xcode: 5, crashlytics: 3, firebase: 5, reactnative: 4 },
    { java: 4, swift: 5, androidstudio: 4 },
    { objc: 5, java: 4, swift: 3, androidstudio: 4, xcode: 4, firebase: 4 },
    { objc: 3, java: 5, swift: 3, xcode: 4, apteligent: 4 },

    // devops
    { docker: 5, kubernetes: 4, aws: 4, ansible: 3, linux: 4 },
    { docker: 4, marathon: 4, aws: 4, jenkins: 5 },
    { docker: 3, marathon: 4, heroku: 4, bamboo: 4, jenkins: 4, nagios: 3 },
    { marathon: 4, heroku: 4, bamboo: 4, jenkins: 4, linux: 3, puppet: 4, nagios: 5 }
  ];
  resultFromKmeans = {check : " this is changed?"};
  kmeans.clusterize(engineers, { k: 4, maxIterations: 5, debug: true }, (err, result) => {
    console.log('----- Results -----');
    console.log(`Iterations: ${result.iterations}`);
    console.log('Clusters: ');
    console.log(result.clusters);
    resultFromKmeans = { ...result.clusters}; //<-- here is the problem. this not override "resultFromKmeans".
  })
  return res.json(resultFromKmeans);
};

//index.js file

const {
  addUserkMeansMatch
} = require('kmeans.js');


app.get('/kmeans', addUserkMeansMatch);
exports.api = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onRequest(app);
```

The problem is: it wants to get from the addUserkMeansMatch function, at the moment only information about the cluster that is found, so I initialize the resultFromKmeans object with the result I want. But it seems that I do not enter the function, or that the value of resultFromKmeans does not change when I run the function. I do not know what to do.

***edit***
This is the revised code, but I do not get to catch. I do not understand why

```
//Add user k-means matches
exports.addUserKmeansMatch = (req, res) => {
  const engineers = [
    // frontend engineers
    { html: 5, angular: 5, react: 3, css: 3 },
    { html: 4, react: 5, css: 4 },
    { html: 4, react: 5, vue: 4, css: 5 },
    { html: 3, angular: 3, react: 4, vue: 2, css: 3 },

    // backend engineers
    { nodejs: 5, python: 3, mongo: 5, mysql: 4, redis: 3 },
    { java: 5, php: 4, ruby: 5, mongo: 3, mysql: 5 },
    { python: 5, php: 4, ruby: 3, mongo: 5, mysql: 4, oracle: 4 },
    { java: 5, csharp: 3, oracle: 5, mysql: 5, mongo: 4 },

    // mobile engineers
    { objc: 3, swift: 5, xcode: 5, crashlytics: 3, firebase: 5, reactnative: 4 },
    { java: 4, swift: 5, androidstudio: 4 },
    { objc: 5, java: 4, swift: 3, androidstudio: 4, xcode: 4, firebase: 4 },
    { objc: 3, java: 5, swift: 3, xcode: 4, apteligent: 4 },

    // devops
    { docker: 5, kubernetes: 4, aws: 4, ansible: 3, linux: 4 },
    { docker: 4, marathon: 4, aws: 4, jenkins: 5 },
    { docker: 3, marathon: 4, heroku: 4, bamboo: 4, jenkins: 4, nagios: 3 },
    { marathon: 4, heroku: 4, bamboo: 4, jenkins: 4, linux: 3, puppet: 4, nagios: 5 }
  ];
  kmeans.clusterize(engineers, { k: 4, maxIterations: 5, debug: true }, (err, result) => {
    res.json(result.cluster111111s)
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
    });
  })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing is that you are returning `res.json(resultFromKmeans)` before it is updated. When you use `kmeans.clusterize` in the above code, you are attaching a callback to it, that essentially says, "Hey, when you finish running clusterize, can you call this function with the result so I can process it?". But because you send back the value before it even finishes, you get the wrong result.

The easiest way to wait for the result is to call `res.json()` from within the callback. Don't forget to handle the value of `err` too!

```
const kmeans = require('kmeans-engine');

exports.addUserkMeansMatch = (req, res) => {
  const engineers = [ /* ... */ ];
  kmeans.clusterize(engineers, { k: 4, maxIterations: 5, debug: true }, (err, result) => {
    console.log('----- Results -----');
    console.log(`Iterations: ${result.iterations}`);
    console.log('Clusters: ');
    console.log(result.clusters);
    res.json(result.clusters); // no need to clone it, just return it as-is.
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I'm trying to fix the error. But I do not succeed, I do not know what I am writing wrong. I added what I did to the question.

Comment: thank you for your help. how can i assign to variable the res.json(result.clusters)? , i want to save this data